# How do I show only available values in the x-axis

Tags: python, plotly

I would like to plot a chart with plotly that shows only the existing values in the x-axis.

When I execute the code below, a chart that looks like in the following image appears:

[image: plot]

The range on the x-axis as well as the range on the y-axis is evenly set from zero up to the maximal value.

```py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly.offline import plot

xValues = [1, 2, 27, 50]
yValues = [7, 1, 2, 3]

trace = go.Scatter( x = xValues, y = yValues, mode='lines+markers', name='high limits' )
plottedData = [trace]

plot( plottedData )
```

Now, I would like to show only the existing values on the x axis. Related to my example, I want just the values [1, 2, 27, 50] to appear. And they should have the same space in between. Is this possible? If yes, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can force the `xaxis.type` to be `category` like this:

```
plot( dict(data=plottedData, layout=go.Layout(xaxis = {"type": "category"} )))
```